# ActiveRecord query for a count of new users by day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to generate a table showing how many users were created each day.

What's the most efficient or elegant ActiveRecord query to do this?

My (simplified) schema looks like this:

```
create_table "users" do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.string   "name"
end
```

I want a table that looks like this, where the integers are a count of new users each day:

```
day              new users
2012-04-01       55
2012-04-02       63
2012-04-03       77
2012-04-04       88
```

I want to generate the table from an array that looks like this:

```
data_table.add_rows( [
  [ Date.parse("2012-04-01"), 55],
  [ Date.parse("2012-04-02"), 63],
  [ Date.parse("2012-04-03"), 77],
  [ Date.parse("2012-04-04"), 88]
] )
```

Comment: Personally I shouldnt do this in the database but in a memory store for example redis.

Comment: Actually I'm using Devise for user management.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this by using the ActiveRecord `group` method like this:

```
@users_created_by_day = User.group("DATE(created_at)").count
```

This will give you a Hash with the dates as the key and the number of users created that day as the value.

Comment: `User.count(:group => 'date(created_at)')` is another option.

Comment: True, though each will run a different SQL query.

Comment: Are you sure about the "different SQL query"? Both should do `select count(*) as count_all, date(created_at) as date_created_at from users group by date(created_at)`.

Comment: Oops! You are correct - I thought that arel would take care of it, but then read the wrong line off my irb session. Thanks for catching it.